# How to prevent a div from disappearing when you hover another div in this same div?

Tags: jquery

I have a div. Inside this div, there is another div. When I hover the "parent" div, the div inside the "parent" div, will fadeIn(). But when I hover the div inside the "parent" div, this div automaticly fadeOut(), but I don't want this to happen. How can I solve this problem?

Since i'm bad at explaining, I made a fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9kAkY/

HTML

```
<div id="preview">
    HOVER THIS BIG DIV

    <div id="previewDesc">
        I don't want this div to fadeOut when I hover over it. 
        How can I prevent this from happening?
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery code I used.

```
   $("#preview").hover(function()
   {
       $("#previewDesc").fadeIn(100);                    
   });

   $("#preview").mouseout(function()
   {
       $("#previewDesc").fadeOut(100);                    
   });
```

This is the CSS I used

```
#preview{
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#previewDesc{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #666666;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: none;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use `mouseout`, [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) provides you with 2 callbacks: one for when you hover in, and one for when you hover out. Use them:

```
$("#preview").hover(
   //called when hovering into the div
   function() {
        $("#previewDesc").fadeIn(100);                    
   },
   //called when hovering out of the div
   function() {
        $("#previewDesc").fadeOut(100); 
   }
);
```

Here is a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kAkY/4/).

Comment: This is actually the one I was looking for! THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9kAkY/3/)

```
$("#preview").mouseenter(function()
   {
       $("#previewDesc").fadeIn(100);                    
   }).mouseleave(function()
   {
       $("#previewDesc").fadeOut(100);                    
   });
```